# Getting the email message in the form it was written(in english,not binary or any other encoding tech) in apex

Tags: apex, trigger, attachment, email2case

I am writing a trigger on attachment  where I need to check whether the value of a   field of the parent  custom object  is  contained in  the email subject line of the email  added as an attachment to the custom object .

Here I  tried converting the attachment blob to string ,but unfortunately its throwing UTF 8 error.I used other methods of EncodingUtil ,but it couldn't help much .

My intention is to decode the email content as a  string without any alteration,then comparing.

Say, field value='Hello'

and the email subject ='RE:Hello'

I want  attachment email blob to  convert into  'RE:Hello'.

(Inbound email handler is outta  context as here email message is added as an attachment  to custom object.I am trying to get the email message in the form it was written(in english,not binary or any other encoding tech) in apex .I am just creating a scenario so that it can be more clear: I have an email to case set up created in my org.When  a case is opened  in some xyz ticket management system,an email is sent to my org and corresponding case record is created.Now when this case is closed ,the requestor is notified that the case is closed.If this requestor replies back,his email  message is attached to the case (one which was earlier created) as an email attachment. I  want to compare the case subject with this  email's  subject line,if the case subject is contained in the email subject line or body,case status would be set to 'Re-opened'.).

Comment: Rather than jump through hoops like this (ignoring backward compatibility), when you save new inbound email attachments to your custom object, would it be possible to store the inbound email's subject as part of the attachment record? That would seem like a much more efficient long term solution.

Comment: Thanks CRMprog for your response ! Matching  the attachment name with the case subject worked.